# Get the name of the current page template from within a plugin without resorting to sniffing the URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the name of the current page template from within a plugin.

I know this is possible, I have seen some plugins that do this. Would I need to include the `$wpdb` DB and run a custom query? Probably need the `$post` global as well to get the id. Just curious if there is an easier way.

I have seen posts that use action hooks to accomplish only running a plugin on certain pages, but these clients have a plugin to make their header and want it to be different for certain templates. Kind of a crazy way to accomplish this IMO, but that is where it is.

Right now I am sniffing the URI and search for a string for the particular page, but I would really prefer to make this more modular.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the page template name?

How about using [get_page_template_slug($post->ID)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug)?

Or you could use [get_page_template()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template) as well.

Or, even better; do a conditional using [is_page_template()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/)

Comment: I am pretty sure these will not work in a plugin. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176536

Answer (score 0):

```
get_query_var('pagename');
List of Query Vars:
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars
or
body_class();
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/
```

Comment: These both throw errors. Can they be run before the loop? I need this to work in a plugin.